# How to configure port-forwarding to enable internal service accessed by another machine?

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I have an existing service which is listening on `127.0.0.1:2009`, and I want to access that service from another machine, so I tried to configure port-forwarding to do it:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d xx.xx.xx.xx --dport 8192 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:2009
```

But it does not work. I even cannot see this rule when I tried to list all the rules of "nat" using:

```
$ sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any errors in the iptables command line above?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get rid of the destination, I have a similar rule and this would be the adapted version to your problem:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8192 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:2009
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 8192 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Otherwise post your complete iptables listing with

```
(sudo) iptables -L -n -v
```

Comment: Yes, with your suggestion, the rule appears, but I still cannot connect to 8192 port from another machine

Comment: i think forwarding should be enabled for this to work.

Comment: Yes, this is mandatory:
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Answer (score 0):

There is a `sysctl` setting preventing `dnat` to loopback.
replace `eth0` below with your external interface traffic is coming in on.

To allow it

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```

and to check the setting.

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/route_localnet
```

Now set your `dnat` to `127.0.0.1` will work.